# Python Coin Change: Incrementing list in return statement?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, python-2.6, tail-recursion, coin-change

Edit: Still working on this, making progress though.

```
def recursion_change(available_coins, tender):
    """
    Returns a tuple containing:
        :an array counting which coins are used to make change, mirroring the input array
        :the number of coins to make tender.

    :coins: List[int]
    :money: int
    :rtype: (List[int], int)
    """
    change_list = [0] * len(available_coins)



    def _helper_recursion_change(change_index, remaining_balance, change_list):
        if remaining_balance == 0:
            return (change_list, sum(change_list))
        elif change_index == -1 or remaining_balance < 0:
            return float('inf')
        else:
            test_a = _helper_recursion_change(change_index-1, remaining_balance, change_list)
            test_b = _helper_recursion_change(_helper_recursion_change(len(available_coins)-1, tender, change_list))

            test_min = min(test_a or test_b)

            if :
                _helper_recursion_change()
            else:
                _helper_recursion_change()
    return 1 + _helper_recursion_change(change_index, remaining_balance-available_coins[change_index], change_list))

print str(recursion_change([1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100], 72)) # Current Output: 5
# Desired Output: ([2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 0], 5)
```

Quick overview: this coin-change algorithm is supposed to receive a list of possible change options and tender. It's supposed to recursively output a mirror array and the number of coins needed to make tender, and I think the best way to do that is with a tuple.

For example:

> > recursion_change([1, 2, 5, 10, 25], 49)
>
> > >> ([0, 2, 0, 2, 1], 5)

Working code sample:

http://ideone.com/mmtuMr

```
def recursion_change(coins, money):
    """
    Returns a tuple containing:
        :an array counting which coins are used to make change, mirroring the input array
        :the number of coins to make tender.

    :coins: List[int]
    :money: int
    :rtype: (List[int], int)
    """
    change_list = [0] * len(coins)

    def _helper_recursion_change(i, k, change_list):
        if k == 0: # Base case: money in this (sub)problem matches change precisely
            return 0
        elif i == -1 or k < 0: # Base case: change cannot be made for this subproblem
            return float('inf')
        else: # Otherwise, simplify by recursing:
            # Take the minimum of:
                # the number of coins to make i cents
                # the number of coins to make k-i cents

            return min(_helper_recursion_change(i-1, k, change_list), 1 + _helper_recursion_change(i, k-coins[i], change_list))
    return (_helper_recursion_change(len(coins)-1, money, change_list))

print str(recursion_change([1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100], 6)) # Current Output: 2

# Desired Output: ([1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0], 2)
```

Particularly, this line:

`1 + _helper_recursion_change(i, k-coins[i], change_list))`

It's easy enough to catch the number of coins we need, as the program does now. Do I have to change the return value to include change_list, so I can increment it? What's the best way to do that without messing with the recursion, as it currently returns just a simple integer.

Replacing change_list in the list above with change_list[i] + 1 gives me a
`TypeError: 'int' object is unsubscriptable` or change_list[i] += 1 fails to run because it's 'invalid syntax'.

Comment: You can't assign within a call, or index into an integer.

Comment: Right. Where is the right place to increment an index, though? If I put a change_list[i] += 1 anywhere else, it just seems to increment change_list[0].